# Search and Replace value in HTML binary file in UNIX

Tags: text-processing, html

I'm trying to search and replace some values in my already created HTML template.
Being a binary file, I've so far been unsuccessful in search and replacing my HTML.

I need to search for string 1111 and replace it with 1234 in here.

```
style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'><span style='color:#1F497D'>1111</span><o:p></o:p></span></p>
```

Please suggest what command can be used as the HTML source code has plenty of HEX chars.

The HTML I want to to replace is https://pastebin.mozilla.org/8920460

Comment: What special characters?    Why hasn't any answer been useful to you?   If I remember correctly, which I usually do, there is nothing in that HTML that would prevent you from using any of the answers.   Perhaps what you need is a proper HTML parses and something that operates on a tree structure rather than text?

Answer (score 1):

Sample file `test.txt`

```
should not touch 1111
<body>
should touch 1111
</body>
should not touch 1111
```

Using `GNU Awk 3.1.7`

```
awk 'BEGIN {s=0};{if (/<body/) {s=1;} else if (/<\/body>/) {s=0;};if (s) {gsub(1111,1234)}};1' test.txt
```

Result

```
should not touch 1111
<body>
should touch 1234
</body>
should not touch 1111
```

Comment: this just works for the one line but I need such a code where in I could replace 1111 with 1234 in the html https://pastebin.mozilla.org/8920460

Comment: @scribbler so if I understand you correct. Would replacing 1111 with 1234 anywhere between the <body> tags work for you?

Comment: Yes that works for me.@zachary

Comment: @scribbler updated answer for new requirements

Comment: this unfortunately doesn't work on the html file which I have provided https://pastebin.mozilla.org/8920460

Comment: @scribbler looks like it's not a plain `<body>`, I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve it with a simple script writen in python:

**replace.py**

```
f = open("index.html",'r') # open file with read permissions
filedata = f.read() # read contents
f.close() # closes file
filedata = filedata.replace("1111", "1234") # replace 1111 with 1234
filedata = filedata.replace("2222", "2345") # you can add as many replace rules as u need
f = open("index.html",'w') # open the same (or another) file with write permissions
f.write(filedata) # update it replacing the previous strings 
f.close() # closes the file
```

then run:

```
python replace.py
```

Comment: nope this didnt work with python. the script should handle all the special character for searching and replacing the html file. https://pastebin.mozilla.org/8920460

Comment: What special characters are you referring to? A HTML file is a text file, not a binary, so please give us a clue as to what is it that's not working.

Comment: It treats html file as an binary file as it has /*.<> kind of special characters where shell has some special meaning for it. We can use \ as escape character but there are plenty of them, so searching for another way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

sed(1)  Stream EDitor is a good tool for (regex) search and replace.

Check
`man 1 sed`

```
sed -e s/foo/bar/g infile > outfile
```

will replace  everything that matches the regular expression "foo" with the substitution "bar".

PS. Use the `-r` flag if you need to use back-references in the substitution part.

Comment: No Oskar, that doesnt work as my html code has many special characters, I need something in my script wherein I can escape characters present in all the code.

Comment: Can you give a more realistic example in your question?

Comment: https://pastebin.mozilla.org/8920460

Comment: above is the sample html in which I want to search and replace.

Comment: I still don't see what a simple regex substitution would fail at here.  And what do you mean by "binary" file?